# Error Encountered When Pushing Code with Azure AD (MSAL) Integration to Azure Web App Using GitHub

Tags: django, azure, github, ssl, azure-active-directory

I have a Django project with a built-in authentication system that works fine in both development (dev), system integration testing (SIT), and production (PROD) environments. After implementing Azure AD integration and starting the server with "sslserver," everything works fine because Django runs on HTTPS. However, when I push the code to the production environment, I encounter an error: "Application error."

I encountered multiple issues during the implementation:

When running the Django server using "runserver," I encountered an error:

```
AADSTS50011: The redirect URI 'http://domain.azurewebsites.net/auth/redirect' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application.
```

I identified this problem when using the sign-in feature, as it failed to authenticate and pick up the correct redirect URI.

After changing the redirect URI from HTTP to HTTPS, the sign-in authentication was successful. However, when Azure AD sent a response to the Django app, another error occurred:

```
You are trying to access "http://domain.azurewebsites.net/auth/redirect," but the return URI is "http://domain.azurewebsites.net/auth/redirect."

[30/Nov/2023 11:46:33] Code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('\x16\x03\x01\x02\x1a\x01\x00\x02\x16\x03\x03M\x12Â;Fþæw')
[30/Nov/2023 11:46:33] You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.
```

This issue arises when the Django project runs on HTTP. Switching to HTTPS might resolve the problem.

So, how can i start server with https on production.